# Redirect to same view with some context

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, httpresponse

I am trying to redirect to a url along with some context data via my views. How can I do that?

Urls:
Project urls.py :

```
url(r'^employee/(?P<emp_code>[0-9a-zA-Z-_@.\s]+)/', include('apps.organisation_roles.urls',namespace='organisation_roles')),
```

organisation_roles/urls.py:

```
url(r'^reward-employee/$', RewardEmployee.as_view(), name='reward_employee'),
```

views:

```
def post(self, request, document=None, *args, **kwargs):
admin_user_id = OrganisationUser.objects.get(organisation_employees=request.user.organisation_user).pk
            Notification.objects.create_and_send(notification_type='ON', send_sms=False, user_id=admin_user_id,
                                                 additional_dict={
                                                     "organisation_name": request.user.organisation_user.organisation.get_name(),
                                                     "message": "You are currently low on gems and your employees are wishing to reward other employees. Please purchase more gems to continue using our services."})
#return render(request,"reward_employee.html",{"alert": "Not enough gems. You cannot reward at present. Contact your organisation."})
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('organisation_roles:reward_employee',kwargs={'emp_code':self.kwargs['emp_code'],"alert": "Not enough gems. You cannot reward at present. Contact your organisation."}))
        #response = HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
        #response.set_cookie('alert', 'Not enough gems. You cannot reward at present. Contact your organisation.')
        #return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

Template:

```
<script>
{% if alert %}
            alert("{{ alert }}");
        {% endif %}
</script>
```

Instead of 'reward_employee.html', I want to give url to my view.

Answer (score 0):

Use    return HttpResponseRedirect, instead of render.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/

Comment: I have tried HttpResponseRedirect('reward_employee.html,"Not enough gems. You cannot reward at present. Contact your organisation.") but it is not working the way i want it to work. I have even tried render_to_response({"alert": "Not enough gems. You cannot reward at present. Contact your organisation."}), this is also not working

Comment: Have you read the link I gave you? Use HttpResponseRedirect, but provide the URL instead of the html template

Comment: return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('organisation_roles:reward_employee', args=(self.kwargs['emp_code'],)),{"alert": "Not enough gems. You cannot reward at present. Contact your organisation."})  this is giving me this error: NoReverseMatch at /employee/103/reward-employee/
u'organisation_roles' is not a registered namespace. Here Organisation_roles is the app name

Comment: You have to include the namespace to your URLs: url(r'........', include('Organisation_roles.urls', namespace='organisation_roles')),

Comment: Thank you for this detail, but still this is not giving my the required alert. See my edited code.

Comment: Is not giving you the alert, but do you get errors anymore? And what is this args=(self.kwargs['emp_code'],)) inside HttpResponseRedirect? Delete it. Your third parameter should be the dictionary containing the variables you want to pass.

Comment: My url to the view has an emp_code variable in it which needs to be specified if we give the path to that view. I removed that portion but then it is giving me this error : "TypeError at /employee/103/reward-employee/
unhashable type: 'dict'"

Comment: Ok, if you need that, the dictionary( the third param of HttpResponseRedirect) should be {"alert": "Not enough gems. You cannot reward at present. Contact your organisation.", "emp_code": self.kwargs['emp_code']}  . If this is till not working please provide the error stack

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /employee/103/reward-employee/
Reverse for 'reward_employee' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'emp_code': u'103', 'alert': 'Not enough gems. You cannot reward at present. Contact your organisation.'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'employee/(?P<emp_code>[0-9a-zA-Z-_@.\\s]+)/reward-employee/$']...
This is the error that is coming now.

Comment: Please edit your post and include the urls.py of your app and the urls.py of your project

Comment: of corse you have an error: you are trying to redirect to `organisation_roles:reward_employee` in your views. So the path would be `employee/(?P<emp_code>[0-9a-zA-Z-_@.\s]+)/reward-employee/`. The URL does not exist, emp_code is not defined in your view. There is a problem in the logic of your prgroam. Which is the view that processes this line `url(r'^reward-employee/$', RewardEmployee.as_view(), name='reward_employee'),` ? you need to know the `emp_code` inside your view in order to redirect to something like `employee/100/reward-employee/`

Answer (score 0):

As you have simple alert, you can set data in cookie and return response.

```
response = HttpResponseRedirect(URL)
response.set_cookie('alert', 'Not enough gems. You cannot reward at present. Contact your organisation.') 
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

After redirecting to url, you can fetch data and delete a cookie.

```
if request.COOKIES.has_key( 'alert' ):
    alert = request.COOKIES[ 'alert' ]
    del request.COOKIES[ 'alert' ]
```

By this way, you can access data, after redirecting to diffrent URL.

Comment: This is not giving me the alert I want to show through my template.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got to give an alert along with redirecting to same page. All I had to do was create a session with boolean value and according pass some context and the alert was showing after redirecting to same view. Here is what I did.

View :

```
def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.session.get('alert'):
            tags = Tag.objects.filter(creator__organisation=request.user.organisation_user.organisation) | \
                   Tag.objects.filter(creator=None)
            context_dict = {'tags': tags, 'employees': request.user.organisation_user.get_employees_managed()}
        else:
            request.session['alert'] = False
            tags = Tag.objects.filter(creator__organisation=request.user.organisation_user.organisation) | \
                   Tag.objects.filter(creator=None)
            context_dict = {'tags': tags, 'employees': request.user.organisation_user.get_employees_managed(),'alert':"Not enough gems. You cannot reward at present. Contact your organisation."}
        return context_dict

@transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, document=None, *args, **kwargs):
admin_user_id = OrganisationUser.objects.get(organisation_employees=request.user.organisation_user).pk
            Notification.objects.create_and_send(notification_type='ON', send_sms=False, user_id=admin_user_id,
                                                 additional_dict={
                                                     "organisation_name": request.user.organisation_user.organisation.get_name(),
                                                     "message": "You are currently low on gems and your employees are wishing to reward other employees. Please purchase more gems to continue using our services."})
            request.session['alert'] = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('organisation_roles:reward_employee',args=(self.kwargs['emp_code'],)))
```

And in template I wrote,

```
<script>
{% if alert %}
            alert("{{alert }}");
        {% endif %}
</script>
```